# From where can I get list of all color patterns used by Google Charts?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

Question is simple, by default Google Charts uses some predefined colors for factors on the charts. First four are:

- Blue #3366CC
- Red #DC3912
- Yellow #FF9900
- Green #109618

Fine. When your chart must display more factors on a chart then it takes:

- Purple #990099
- Sea blue #0099C6
- Pastel pink #DD4477

Above names have been given by myself so they aren't official but color values are. The point is **what colors are next**? Is the list of next colors infinite?

Can someone point me to the source where can I find all of them? I went through the whole manual and found nothing. I could render bunch of factors in the fiddle but I'm feeling that it won't cover all possible colors.

Thank you for your help.

The reason why I want to get those color values is that I want to use `C3js` / `D3js` in a parallel with Google Charts and to keep consistency I have to provide D3 with a list of predefined colors like:

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
            ['data2', 50, 20, 10, 40, 15, 25],
            ['data3', 130, 220, 140, 200, 250, 450],
            ['data4', 250, 320, 210, 240, 215, 225],
            ['data5', 430, 500, 400, 280, 290, 350],
            ['data6', 100, 120, 310, 340, 415, 225]
        ]
    },
    color: {
        pattern: ['#1f77b4', '#aec7e8', '#ff7f0e', '#ffbb78', '#2ca02c', '#98df8a', '#d62728', '#ff9896', '#9467bd', '#c5b0d5', '#8c564b', '#c49c94', '#e377c2', '#f7b6d2', '#7f7f7f', '#c7c7c7', '#bcbd22', '#dbdb8d', '#17becf', '#9edae5']
    }
});
```

Obviously I want to replace `color.pattern` array with what Google Chars uses.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you seen this page yet? http://there4.io/2012/05/02/google-chart-color-list/

Comment: Also, another page with more options (I think this is more specific to google rather than google charts). https://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html#color-color-palette

Comment: No, I haven't. That's cool and it gives me 20 colors! But last question to solve the problem? is the list fixed? What value will be used for the 21st factor? Blue (1st)? I think I have to create a fiddle to check it.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure about the last question. Create a fiddle and let's take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. So here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/slick/xcpxz738/

```
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
    ['factor1',     1],
    ['factor2',     1],
    ['factor3',     1],
    ['factor4',     1],
    ['factor5',     1],
    ['factor6',     1],
    ['factor7',     1],
    ['factor8',     1],
    ['factor9',     1],
    ['factor10',     1],
    ['factor11',     1],
    ['factor12',     1],
    ['factor13',     1],
    ['factor14',     1],
    ['factor15',     1],
    ['factor16',     1],
    ['factor17',     1],
    ['factor18',     1],
    ['factor19',     1],
    ['factor20',     1],
    ['factor21',     1],
    ['factor22',     1],
    ['factor23',     1],
    ['factor24',     1],
    ['factor25',     1],
  ]);
```

25 factors and 21st doesn't use blue (from the 1st). I'm pretty sure that I won't use so many factors. I case of that I will simply put more factors to this fiddle to check next colors.

I will simply use color picker to copy and paste colors to my C3.
Than you mwilson anyway. I'll give you upvote.

Answer (score 30):

This is an old post but I couldn't find the complete list on the web.
Apparently Google uses 31 colors then loops (the 32nd color is the 1st blue). 
Here is the full list :

```
#3366cc
#dc3912
#ff9900
#109618
#990099
#0099c6
#dd4477
#66aa00
#b82e2e
#316395
#994499
#22aa99
#aaaa11
#6633cc
#e67300
#8b0707
#651067
#329262
#5574a6
#3b3eac
#b77322
#16d620
#b91383
#f4359e
#9c5935
#a9c413
#2a778d
#668d1c
#bea413
#0c5922
#743411
```

Answer (score 3):

Two resources that may help you with the Google Chart Color List

- https://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html#color-color-palette
- http://there4.io/2012/05/02/google-chart-color-list/

Answer (score 1):

This is not a direct answer, but in case someone will be looking for a set of darker colors for the charts and gets here like I did, here's the list created using https://pinetools.com/darken-color and list of colors provided by LouiseS:

```
colors: ['#264c99', '#a52a0d', '#bf7200',
            '#0c7012', '#720072', '#007294',
            '#b72153', '#4c7f00', '#8a2222',
            '#244a6f', '#723372', '#197f72',
            '#7f7f0c', '#4c2699', '#ac5600',
            '#680505', '#4b0c4d', '#256d49',
            '#3f577c', '#2c2e81', '#895619',
            '#10a017', '#8a0e62', '#d30b79',
            '#754227', '#7e930e', '#1f5969',
            '#4c6914', '#8e7b0e', '#084219',
            '#57270c'
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

[LouiseS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56495465/5184092) answer but beautified (Javascript)

```
// Google chart colors
var colours = ['#3366cc','#dc3912','#ff9900','#109618',
                '#990099','#0099c6','#dd4477','#66aa00',
                '#b82e2e','#316395','#994499','#22aa99',
                '#aaaa11','#6633cc','#e67300','#8b0707',
                '#651067','#329262','#5574a6','#3b3eac',
                '#b77322','#16d620','#b91383','#f4359e',
                '#9c5935','#a9c413','#2a778d','#668d1c',
                '#bea413','#0c5922','#743411'];
```

Highlighted for visual reference
[image]