# Google pie chart colors

Tags: php, graph, pie-chart

I just have a question: I would like to know what are the exact colours (in hexadecimal code) used in the google pie chart by default. I've searched the internet but I can't find them.

Thank you for your help!

[Pie chart example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QxFWR.png)

Comment: I think https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32131668/from-where-can-i-get-list-of-all-color-patterns-used-by-google-charts gives a list.

Comment: Yeah absolutely that is exactly what i was looking for. Thank you :)